# Iterate over array of results, two by two

Tags: php, mysql, loops, array-map

I have an array coming from a SQL query that follows the following format:

```
[ 
  ["2012-10-01", 1, 3890], 
  ["2012-10-01", 0, 8900], 
  ["2012-09-21", 0, 8900], 
  ["2012-09-21", 1, 8900], 
  ...
]
```

At the end I want to have the counts for 0s and 1s. So for example, for the date 2012-10-01, I would have that the value 1 have a count 3890 and the value 0 have a count 8900.  I want to know how I can iterate this array in order to build a final array like this:

```
$final_array["value0"]["2012-10-01"] = 3890
$final_array["value1"]["2012-10-01"] = 8900
$final_array["total"]["2012-10-01"] = 12790
```

Taking into account that it can happen that a date doesn't have a count for value 0 or 1, and the order of value 0 and 1 is not always the same.

So the first example could be like this:

```
[ 
   ["2012-10-01", 1, 3890], 
   ["2012-09-21", 1, 8900], 
   ["2012-09-21", 0, 8900], 
   ...
]
```

As you can see the first date is lacking of value 0 and the final array would still have to have it like this:

```
   $final_array["value0"]["2012-10-01"] = 3890
   $final_array["value1"]["2012-10-01"] = 0
```

Comment: what is the value of `$final_array["value1"]["2012-10-01"]` in your second example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code. You really should try to work it out yourself first, because this is basic array mapping.

```
foreach($initialarray as $data){
    $finalarray["value".$data[1]][$data[0]]=$data[2]; 
}
```

EDIT: Here is code that fulfils your updated requirements:

```
$initialarray = array(array("2012-10-01", 1, 3890), array("2012-09-21", 1, 8900), array("2012-09-21", 0, 8900));
$finalarray["value0"]=array();
$finalarray["value1"]=array();
foreach($initialarray as $data){
    $finalarray["value".$data[1]][$data[0]]=$data[2]; 
    $finalarray["value".round(cos($data[1]*pi()/2))][$data[0]]=$finalarray["value".round(cos($data[1]*pi()/2))][$data[0]]?$finalarray["value".round(cos($data[1]*pi()/2))][$data[0]]:0;
}
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($finalarray);
echo "<pre>";
```

[DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/sid-inp)

Comment: This won't work if, as I said, the values of 0,1 are not ordered by date.

Comment: @HommerSmith This should work just fine, could you explain more why that wouldn't work?

Comment: Yes sorry. Imagine that for the first date, there is no 0 value. In that case I would have to create an entrance like this:

$finalarray["value0"][$data[0]]=0

Comment: If there is no 0 value for the first date, the "value0" index will still be defined on the array as long as there is at least one entry for 0 values on some day. Your last comment is crucial information. You should include this in the question.

Comment: Yes, but it needs to be defined for all dates that there is value 1, and the other way around. So, all dates have to have value0 and value1.

Comment: `all dates have to have value0 and value1.` whereas they clearly do not in your source array. You can have lossy array transformations, but you can't have array transformations that **make** new information. How is the script to know what "all dates" are, when they aren't even in the source array?

Comment: @Asad I have edited my question, because I didn't add that I would have to add the two values (0,1) for each date and put it in a new key in the final array. That is what makes it tricky of doing everything in one iteration, right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18453/discussion-between-hommer-smith-and-asad)

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($array1 as $value){
    $final_array["value".$value[1]][$value[0]] = $value[2];
}
```

with `$array1` as your first array

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
$result = array('value0' => array(), 'value1' => array());
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $result[('value' . $value[1])][$value[0]] = $value[2];
}
```